# Set Antd's Menu defaultSelectedKeys value using React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, antd

I'm using antd for building a react application. I'm using antd's Layout to design the layout. Also, I'm using react-router for routing and redux for state management.

In antd's Menu I've set the defaultSelectedKeys to a blank array so that when page loads I don't want to show the active menu item. Instead, When the user accesses a certain page{Component) using application URL in the browser, then that page's menu item should be active.

For example, by default **defaultSelectedKeys** array will be blank. So no menu item will be active initially. When the application loads and react-router routes to the home component then the home menu item should be active.

For this, I'm using useEffect hook to dispatch an action with the menu key when a particular component is mounted.

Example Home Component:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { CURRENT_COMPONENT } from "./../reducers/types";
export default function HomeComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: CURRENT_COMPONENT,
      payload: { component: "Landing", sideBarMenuKey: "1" }
    });
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>This is a home componet </h1>
      <br />
      ...
      <br />
      <br />
      ...
      <br />
      <br />
      ...
      <br />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Up here in the useEffect I'm dispatching an action to the reducer with **sideBarMenuKey: "1"** and it is dispatching perfectly when this component mounts and able to receive the state change in Layout component as well using the react-redux useSelector hook.

Example Layout Component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Layout, Menu, Breadcrumb } from "antd";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomeComponent from "./Home";
import AboutComponent from "./About";
const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;

export default function LayoutComponent() {
  const sideBarMenuKey = useSelector(
    state => state.currentComponetReducer.sideBarMenuItemKey
  );

  console.log(sideBarMenuKey);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Layout className="layout">
        <Header>
          <div className="logo" />
          <Menu
            theme="dark"
            mode="horizontal"
            defaultSelectedKeys={[sideBarMenuKey]}
            style={{ lineHeight: "64px" }}
          >
            <Menu.Item key="1">Home</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">About</Menu.Item>

          </Menu>
        </Header>
        <Content style={{ padding: "0 50px" }}>
          <Breadcrumb style={{ margin: "16px 0" }}>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>List</Breadcrumb.Item>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>App</Breadcrumb.Item>
          </Breadcrumb>
          <div style={{ background: "#fff", padding: 24, minHeight: 280 }}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutComponent} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Content>
        <Footer style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED
        </Footer>
      </Layout>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Even though I'm receiving the state change in the Layout Component and when I use sideBarMenuKey in antd's Menu prop as **defaultSelectedKeys={[sideBarMenuKey]}** the menu item doesn't get active state.

**Sample Example:**
I've created a sample codesandbox example. The link is below 
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-antd-react-starter-ytxko

I've created a Layout, Home and About components. Initially, when you log in it will show Home component. If you want to render the About component, then change the browser URL in the codesandbox to https://url/about. Both in Home and About component I'm dispatching an action with sideBarMenuKey and the state is also getting updated. But the menu item is not getting active.

Comment: Your code "looks" fine except it has some syntax errors like `checkingIsAnAdmin]`, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), try adding a minimal [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antdstart-n8n96) which represents your problem.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for your reply, I've added minimal codesandbox code which represents my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing `defaultSelectedKeys` to `selectedKeys` should make it work:

```
<Menu
  theme="dark"
  mode="horizontal"
  selectedKeys={[sideBarMenuKey]}
  style={{ lineHeight: "64px" }}
>
  <Menu.Item key="1">Home</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="2">About</Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

Putting `NavLink` inside the `Menu.Item` will allow you to switch from a nav tab to another.

```
<Menu
  theme="dark"
  mode="horizontal"
  selectedKeys={[sideBarMenuKey]}
  style={{ lineHeight: "64px" }}
>
  <Menu.Item key="1">
    <NavLink to="/">nav 1</NavLink>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="2">
    <NavLink to="/about">nav 1</NavLink>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="3">nav 3</Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

You can see it in action here

[image: Edit styled-antd-react-starter]

Comment: It may work but you can notice from his code that he doesn't want to make `Menu` controllable component.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean when you said "he doesn't want to make Menu controllable component"? Is it that he doesn't want the menu to change active on click?

Comment: When you are setting a `selectedKeys`, from this point you need to manage `Menu` state, without it the `Menu` is `uncontrollable` and managed itself. Trying to switch to another nav tab will not work with your example.

Comment: Putting `NavLink` inside the Menu.Item will allow you to switch from a nav tab to another. (see edit)

Comment: Instead of using defaultSelectedKeys I had to use selectedKeys. I didn't know that selectedKeys is there for Menu. I should read antd's documentation properly before posting anything here. Anyway thanks Dennis and Julien for taking your time and helping me. Much appreciated  :)

Comment: Thanks for this I encountered this also and I thought I'm just doing something wrong with React and Redux. Driving me crazy with this one and the AntDesign docs did not tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const [sideBarMenuKey, setSideBarMenuKey] = useState(1);
      <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline"  defaultSelectedKeys={[sideBarMenuKey]}>
                  <Menu.Item  key="1" icon={<BirthIcon style={{ paddingRight: '10px' }} />}
                              onClick={ () => {
                                  setSideBarMenuKey(1)
                                  setShowBirth(true);

                              }
                              } >
                      Birth
                  </Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item   key="2"
                               icon={<DeathIcon style={{ paddingRight: '10px' }} />}
                               onClick={ () => {
                                   setSideBarMenuKey(2)
                                   setShowBirth(false)

                               } }>




                      Death
                  </Menu.Item>

              </Menu>
```

Using hooks look on to this